# how to use Oracle decode Select statment

Tags: oracle10g

```
SELECT DECODE(SEND_BEN_INFO1_7495_1,
             'YOUR UTR SBINH13246802674 RTN',
              ( REPLACE(
                         REPLACE('YOUR UTR SBINH13246802674 RTN',
                                 'YOUR UTR',
                                 '')
                        , 'RTN',
                          '')
                       ),
              'Null'
              )"UTR" 
  FROM NT_N06 
 where value_dt='20121214' 
   and MSG_SUMMARY_ID=181521.
```

This is not working? How can use select statement with in decode function.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What are the values in the table and what output are you getting?

Comment: the input value is YOUR UTR SBINH13246802674 RTN. i am getting only Null. That is wrong.give me suggestion

Comment: The query seems correct. Example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/17128).

Comment: Can you please explain how it is works? because SEND_BEN_INFO1_7495_1-this is column name and the input value is YOUR UTR SBINH13246802674 RTN. how it working?

Comment: Are you sure your table has the value `YOUR UTR SBINH13246802674 RTN`? Even if there is a slight change in the numbers, this will give you null.

Comment: Are you getting null or no rows returned. does you value 'YOUR UTR SBINH13246802674 RTN' satifies the where condition. where value_dt='20121214' and MSG_SUMMARY_ID=181521